# (Type) Syntax in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am currently working with `CoreAudio` in `Swift`. And there is a structure called `AudioBufferList`. It has a property `mBuffers`, which has type `(AudioBuffer)` and described as "A variable length array of `AudioBuffer` structures".

Since `Array` in `Swift` is defined as `[Type]`, and I can not find anything about declaring an `Array` as `(Type)` I do wonder how is that possible that `(Type)` is also an `Array` and how to work with it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Without more context your question is quite unclear. Please include the actual code you're having problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an array, it's the same as `AudioBuffer` without parentheses.

The manual says:

> You can put parentheses around a named type or a compound type. However, adding parentheses around a type doesn’t have any effect. For example, `(Int)` is equivalent to `Int`. ([from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html))

Comment: So the `Apple` documentation about `AudioBufferList` is simply misleading then.

Comment: @Igor I think the reason for having parentheses in the documentation is that the source file is generated automatically from Objective-C definitions, and nobody took time to clean it up manually.